# How do I overcome typescript's spread operator limitation?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, ecmascript-6

I've tried declaring to no avail. Here is the simple thing I'd like to do:

```
this.scoreStack = [...Array(3).keys()];
```

Apparently, typescript does not support destructuring this way.
I receive:

> Symbol "keys" cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in an
>   inaccessible module

Is there a way that I can define the keys() method and get over this limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can define the keys() method and get over this limitation

You can declare this quite easily:

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        keys():string[];
    }
}

const x = [...Array(3).keys()];
```

Comment: Well, it worked at the compiling-check, but not after compilation. For it to work we would need to export to ES2015 (ES6) and then use Babel.

Answer (score 2):

`Array#keys` is a new method in ES6.

Your code snippet compiles okay for me, but you have to set `-t es2015` (which is marked "experimental").

Comment: Wouldn't that output me to ES2015 directly?? I'd like to stay with the ES5

Answer (score 1):

`Array(3).keys()`return an iterator.To use spread operator on iterators and target es5 use the `--downlevelIteration` switch.

As per TypeScript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Use of `downlevelIteration` switch provides full support for iterables in `for..of`, spread and destructuring when targeting ES5 or ES3.